# How to get to monitor mode Kali Linux on Rasberry pi 4? (airmon-ng, iwconfig don't work)

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, raspberry-pi, broadcom, airmon-ng

#### Method 1: Airmon-ng - (don't work)

`airmon-ng check kill`
`airmon-ng start wlan0`

- Make wlan0mon, everything looks fine, but after some time (around 50 seconds) using some tools like `airgeddon` or `airlay-ng`, my Raspberry start lagging. For example if I type `iwconfig` I must wait 6 seconds to show respond from Raspberry and tools stopped working when I try to stop `wlan0mon` or start Network Manager it also doesn't work. When I type `top`, there isn't any high recourse process what can cause lagging.
  [image]

#### Method 2: Iwconfig - (don't work)

`ifconfig wlan0 down`
`iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor`
`ifconfig wlan0 up`

- Normally change to monitor mode, but when I try some tools like airgeddon or airplay-ng it says some errors and I can't use them.
  [image]

#### Info

[image]

- I tried reinstall whole Kali Linux
- Reinstall firmware: `apt install --reinstall kalipi-re4son-firmware`
- `apt-get update`
- `apt-get full-upgrade`
- `apt install -y kali-linux-large`

Is it some software issue or hardware issue or do I need to buy some Wi-Fi adapter?
Thanks for answering, any help is really appreciated, I'm just beginner with Kali Linux and Raspberry.

Comment: If you're a beginner with both Kali and Raspberries, I'd recommend dropping 1 and first learning the other. Kali is not for beginners.

Comment: But it should work. Even if i am beginner.

Comment: Always include the actual **text** for errors. They might mean a lot to somebody trying to know what is happening. Things like *it says some errors and I can't use them.* don't help us figure out the problem or how to fix it. Could you add the errors to your question?

Comment: But i had include the errors. With method 2 (iwconfig) If I try to find network with airgeddon it didn't work and automatically sad Not network found and in airmon-ng it sad Failed initializing wireless card wlan0 but in the picture you can see that i have monitor mode. And in method 1 there wasn't any errors just it start lagging and i couldn't stop wlan0mon or start Network Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry pi had Nexmon patches for its wireless controller. If you want to use monitor mode, you would have to download older controllers and software, which is hard. So I recommend using a better usb external wifi antena.

As you can see here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=253695